# Partition of an intrval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Can we define a partition for an interval which is not closed i.e. it is of the form $(a,b),(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$?

P.S. Every book has defined partition for the closed interval $[a,b].$

Comment: One can define $[a, b] = \cup_{i}(a_i, b_i)$

Comment: Are you asking why Riemann integration is only defined over a closed bounded interval $[a, b]$ but not other types of interval?

Comment: @Kevin I didn't understand.Can you explain?

Comment: @AlexVong Yes. I am asking why Riemann integration is only defined over a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ but not other types of interval?

Comment: I think it is because we want the function to be bounded, a function defined on a closed bounded interval is always bounded. Also, for a bounded $f$, the value of the integral doesn't depend on the end points for Riemann integral. So for any sensible definition for "integral" of $f$ over $(a, b)$, $(a, b]$ or $[a, b)$, its value should equal to the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[a, b]$. Since nothing new happens, why bother to define it in the first place? For unbounded function, we have improper integral to address your problem.

Comment: @Kevin How will defining the closed interval as union of open intervals solve our problem? We actually are asking here can we, infact, make partition of a semi - open interval? As far as I know, the end points of partition must be included in it. Is it correct? Or is there a method to make partition of an open or semi - open interval?